# how to open desktop folder in electronjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

Have a task in which I should open data coming from back-end in electron as in desktop folder, like that

[image]

have no idea how to do that

For example I'm getting data `{id:1, foldername: 'test'}` and I need to show it in folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shell`

```
const {shell} = require('electron') 
shell.openPath('folderpath')
```

here is the shell docs https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/shell.md